# React - uncallable expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code set up in React.

```
const useToggle = (initialValue : boolean) => {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(initialValue)
  const toggle = () => {
    setBool(!bool)
  }
  return [bool, toggle]
}

const Test : FC = () => {
  const [bool, toggle] = useToggle(false)  
  return (    
    <div>
      boolean value: {bool}
      <button onClick={() => {
        toggle()
      }}>Toggle</button>

    </div>

  )
}
```

On the line with `toggle()` I'm getting the following error:

`This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'boolean | (() => void)' are callable.
    Type 'false' has no call signatures.`

However, the error goes away if I change the `<button>` element to this:

```
<button onClick={() => toggle}>
```

I don't quite understand what the difference is. How exactly does this fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error goes away because in this version: `<button onClick={() => toggle}>` you're not actually invoking the function. You've created an arrow function that returns a reference to the `toggle` function.

In your `useToggle` method, use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) or an explicit type declaration for the method:

```
// const assertion
const useToggle = (initialValue : boolean) => {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(initialValue)
  const toggle = () => {
    setBool(!bool)
  }
  return [bool, toggle] as const;
}

const Test : FC = () => {
  const [bool, toggle] = useToggle(false)  
  return (    
    <div>
      boolean value: {bool}
      <button onClick={() => {
        toggle()
      }}>Toggle</button>

    </div>

  )
}
```

```
// return type declaration
// const assertion
const useToggle = (initialValue : boolean) : [string, Function] => {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(initialValue)
  const toggle = () => {
    setBool(!bool)
  }
  return [bool, toggle];
}

const Test : FC = () => {
  const [bool, toggle] = useToggle(false)  
  return (    
    <div>
      boolean value: {bool}
      <button onClick={() => {
        toggle()
      }}>Toggle</button>

    </div>

  )
}
```

The reason this problem exists has to do with [Tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) types (what React hooks return). Since your `useToggle` method didn't specify what was being returned from a function, TS tries to infer it. It sees an Array literal and types it as an Array literal, not understanding the underlying types inside. There's an [outstanding RFC](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16896) to change this behaviour but adding proper types (or the const assertion fix) gets around it.

Comment: LMulvey - thanks for your answer. Can you clarify what you mean by "you've created an error function" ?

Comment: Oops, typo. Meant to say an arrow function. I've corrected!

Comment: Cool. But in the original line of code, `<button onClick={() => {
        toggle()
      }}>`, does it not have the same effect? toggle() won't actually get invoked until someone triggers the onClick event.

Comment: Not exactly. You're right – in both examples, the arrow function being passed to `onClick` won't be invoked until someone clicks the button. The difference between `() => toggle` and `() => { toggle() }` is that, in the first one, you're only returning a reference to `toggle`, you're not invoking it. In the second example, you're actually invoking `toggle()` in the body of the arrow function.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer for your time. Thanks for the explanation - now I understand the difference. But I'm not still not understanding why the original line of code, `<button onClick={() => { toggle() }}>`, is leading to the error "This expression is not callable"

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer that hopefully provides a little insight as to why TS was throwing the error (admittedly the error is not very helpful). Hopefully that helps you a bit more! Appreciate the upvote regardless and glad you have your problem sorted.

Comment: Now I get it. :) Thanks for your patience and time with this one!